# Scroll page down after linking by anchor

Tags: javascript, php, css

This question was placed and answer here: 
[How to scroll page down after anchor navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287376/how-to-scroll-page-down-after-anchor-navigation/57432465#57432465)

some years ago... I'm trying to use it but it does not work. The "localidades" anchor still moves to under the navbar and not below it. What am I missing?

Below is my code (Joomla 3.9.5):

Any help from anyone, please?

```
<div id="navbar">
  <a href="<?php echo $arturl; ?>#localidades">Localidades</a>
  <a href="<?php echo $arturl; ?>#informacoes">Informações</a>
  <a href="<?php echo $arturl; ?>#destaques">Destaques</a>
  <a href="<?php echo $arturl; ?>#temas">Temas</a>
</div>

<?php $document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScriptDeclaration('
$(\'a\').click(function(){
    var height= $("#navbar").outerHeight();
    var pos = $($(this).attr("href")).position().top;
    $("body").scrollTop(pos - height);
    return false;
})
'); ?>

<section id="localidades">
...
</section>
```

Fernando

Comment: If `$arturl` is not empty, the `href` attribute will not be relative to the current page, and `$($(this).attr("href"))` will not work.

Comment: Thanks Maxime. $arturl is not empty because in current Joomla version if I write href="#localidades" it links to https://www.homepage.com/#localidades and not https://www.homepage.com/currentpage#localidades

Comment: Have you checked your position values to ensure they are correct? I would start there and make sure you're pushing it down enough.

Comment: Yes, plumwd. I've replaced "pos - height" by value "100" (the bar is 50px high) just to check, and the link still jumps to the top of the screen, not below navbar.

Comment: Here is a minimized version of what I'm trying to do

https://www.visitarportugal.pt/expnavbar.php

If I click on either Ponto 1 or Ponto 2 it should jump to below the bar, but it jumps to the top of the window.

I've added onclick call in href in the first link, but no change.

Any hint? :(